# JavaFx: Continuous Model Rotating using Timeline Animation

Tags: javafx

I have a csv file with all the roll, pitch and yaw values. This file has around 11000 lines of roll, pitch and yaw values.
I am trying to rotate a 3D model after reading each line of three values. I am reading the csv file using openCSV and store it in ArrayList. Now using foreach loop, I calculate the 3D rotation axis point using Point3D and angle of rotation using some mathematical expression.

Motive: Rotate the model with the angle for each set of r, p and y values.

My try: creating a for-each loop for each set of r, p and y values. And within each loop, I am trying to calculate the angle and using timeline class, trying to animate the model as soon as it gets the angle.

Current Scenario: I am able to rotate the 3D model but just for last set of r, p and y values. It does not rotate for every set of values. I don't understand what's going wrong in my code.

Code below:

```
for (Parameters listValues : list) {
            double rollValue = Double.parseDouble(listValues.getRoll());
            double pitchValue = Double.parseDouble(listValues.getPitch());
            double yawValue = Double.parseDouble(listValues.getYaw());

            //lines of code calculating mathematical expression

            //calculating angle of rotation
            double angle = Math.acos((A11 + A22 + A33 - 1d) / 2d);
            if (angle != 0d) {
                double denom = 2d * Math.sin(angle);
                Point3D p = new Point3D((A32 - A23) / denom, (A13 - A31) / denom, (A21 - A12) / denom);
                modelGroup.setRotationAxis(p);
                modelGroup.setRotate(Math.toDegrees(angle));

                //timeline animation for each for-each loop
                Timeline t = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(5000),
                        new KeyValue(modelGroup.rotateProperty(), modelGroup.getRotate() +  Math.toDegrees(angle))));
                t.play();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are starting 11000 animations at once, all running in parallel and lasting for the same duration...

Comment: How do I make them run one after another for each set of values with a smooth transition?